# combine two mysql fields and update a third one with result using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a database table that contain two fields "Categories" and "Tags"

i need to create a third field lets say called Keywords as the result of combining both categories and tags

so `$Keywords = $tags." ".$categories;`

can you help me please on how to achieve this

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this purely in SQL:

```
alter table Mytable add column Keywords varchar(255);
update Mytable set Keywords = concat(Categories, ' ', Tags);
```